# jQuery Mobile message loading cannot display if a synch request is invoked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm create a mobile website and using jQuery Mobile plugin. In the page, I need to call to a service by ajax and it's synch, while the request is sent and has response, a loading message should be displayed

It works well with **Firefox**, however with **Chrome**, or mobile device (safari on iOS), the loading message couldn't display, I have change the asynch to false to make it works, it's not what i expected

Following is my draft code

```
function callService() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testservice',
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            // Dosomething
        }
    });
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
}
```

Anyone have the same issue? any suggestion for this case

--- UPDATE ---

I add the sample on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ndkhoiits/jvqQJ/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look on the beforeSend() and complete() functions which will be called before and after the ajax request is done, i.e. somethink like:

```
function callService() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'testservice',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    }
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        // Dosomething
    }
});
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

}

Docs at [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, however it doesn't work with Chrome, with Firefox it's OK. Please check my draft at http://jsfiddle.net/ndkhoiits/jvqQJ/

Comment: I have a similar problem here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985589/jquerymobile-with-backbone-showing-loading-spinner/13987841#comment19355043_13987841