# jquerymobile with backbone showing loading spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am using jQuery mobile with backbone

I have disabled the jquery mobile routing and use backbones which all works well

here is that config

```
define(['jquery'], function($){

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
});
});
```

then on my ajax calls for my views I use this code

```
     $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); },
            url: this.template,
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                compiled = _.template(data);
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            }
        });
```

This shows the loader fine in firefox but does not work on chrome or my ios device?

can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I so this problem few times (I am 100 % sure this is it), async : false will lock your browser while doing ajax call (for some reason only firefox works correctly). So change async: false to true and watch what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit browsers like Chrome/safari/android/iOS have a problem with jQM and async: false ajax call. They will get locked while ajax call is processing. Firefox don't have such problem, for whatever reason.

Change:

```
async: false,
```

to:

```
async: true,
```

If async: false is crucial to you app functionality and you want to prevent user interaction while ajax is working, display a transparent div overlay over whole app. Do it in beforesend state and remove it in a success or a failure state.

Comment: I am using a 

$(".ui-loader").css("display", "block");

and then a 

$(".ui-loader").css("display", "none");

but this still isnt working in Chrome.. surely I am just showing that div and then hiding it.. how can that not work

Comment: The main reason I need this is that I have a 2mb json file being loaded for one of the pages that needs async = false and while that is loading (before shows view/new page) I want to user to be able to see data is loading